# gradle create new java class based on copy

Tags: java, regex, replace, gradle, rename

I have a structure of old bean object in a dedicate package

I want to copy them to a test folder so when I update them I can ensure that new version are compatible with new one

To avoid any naming issue old bean will be rename during copy
This make the copy but the class cannot compile because className != filename

```
task saveOldBean(type: Copy) {
  from('src/main/java/project/bean/') {
      include '**/*Bean.java'
  }
  into 'src/test/java/project/bean/'
  rename '(.*).java', '$1Old.java'
}
```

So i try to replace ClassName in file using same kind of feature (ie regexp)

```
task saveOldBean(type: Copy) {
   from('src/main/java/project/bean/') {
     include '**/(.*Bean).java'
     filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [$1: $1Old])
   }
   into 'src/test/java/project/bean/'
  rename '(.*).java', '$1Old.java'
}
```

This fails, so if you have any suggestion to make this "rename" works, you are welcome

Comment: Renaming the file name of a java file means you will need to rename the associated class name and any reference made to it as well.

Comment: Hello, in that case, this is just a "backup bean",  I can rename it because I want a "saved copy".  This copy will not replace the old class, it is a kind of backup. I don't need to go throught all code... IDE do it for me. But thanks for this information it is always good to keep that in minds

Answer (score 0):

after some tries here is an implementation

```
task backupBean(type: Copy) {
  def TAG_PREVIOUS="Backup";
  def newEnd = "${TAG_PREVIOUS}.java";

  from('src/main/java') {
    include '**/*Bean.java'
  }
  into 'src/test/java'
  rename { String fileName -> 
    fileName.replace('.java', newEnd)
  }

  eachFile {  FileCopyDetails fileInfo ->
    def fileName = fileInfo.name;
    def oldClassName =  fileName.replace(newEnd, "");
    def newClassName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".java"));

    filter{ it.replaceAll("$oldClassName","${newClassName}")}
    filter{ it.replaceAll("public final class","/*${version}*/\npublic final class")}

    println "save [$oldClassName] to [$newClassName]"
  }
}
```